# Using font-face on IE 11: it takes some tries to set the font

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[www.sorialconstrucciones.com](http://www.sorialconstrucciones.com)

Im using `font-face` for some headings and paragraphs, but when I load the page on IE 11, it shows the texts using `Times new roman types`, and the the `font-face` types, then the `Times new roman` again, and finally set to the font to the `font-face` type. **All this in less than a second**.

Any help?

**EDIT:** as the first commenter of my post told me, I have created a minimized demo [here](http://www.sorialconstrucciones.com/prueba), but the problem persist (font-face style flashing on IE 11). This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: MontserratBold;
    src: url(MontserratBold.ttf);
  }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background: red">
  <p style="font-family: 'MontserratBold'">jkflasdfas faks faksfj </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an interesting phenomenon. Can you provide a minimized demo case for an analysis? A link to a live page is not a suitable problem description. There is probably no good fix to the “flash of unstyled content” (a fix that would not involve too many problems and risks), but flashing between default font and declared font twice is unusual. In any case, setting a suitable sans-serif font as the second option in `font-family` would make the phenomenon less disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your font file, define identical names for Fontname, Family name and Name and export your TTF. You can use the [FontForge](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/) application.

And then again convert it for web (EOT, WOFF).

[Read](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/)

Make it work by downloading version of the TTF font and converted it for web.

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mregular';
    src: url('fonts/mregular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/mregular.eot?iefix') format('opentype'),
         url('fonts/mregular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/mregular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: This does not address the question. The point is that the font works, but with flash of unstyled text.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I thought this might help out as it is the correct way of using external font-family in IE, may be I got wrong in my assumption.